# Can't get Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Live to load properly on Apple iMac PowerPC

Tags: powerpc

I've tried 2 different ISOs (one that I burned and a copy from eBay) and tried nearly every bootloader option when I boot from the Live CD. All i get is colored horizontal lines and no text on the screen after I enter a boot option. I can hear the disc spinning like it's trying to load something but it seems there is something wrong with the graphics.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the PowerPC version of Ubuntu.  Intel versions won't work right with PowerPC computers.

- [Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop for PowerPC](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/release/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-powerpc.iso)
- [Ubuntu 12.04 Alternate for PowerPC](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/release/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-powerpc.iso)

These are the official links from [cdimage.ubuntu.com](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com) .

Read the [PowerPC support page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPC) on the Ubuntu Wiki for more information.

Comment: Both discs are PowerPC, but I will try the 12.04 Alternate ISO.